# How to redirect form action to external link after getting form feild value after theming of a external html page

Tags: theming, forms, redirection

I have enabled a .tpl.php file in theme in drupal 7 which contain a form field. So my requirement is to redirect the from field action to another external link after getting value from that from field. The form field value i.e  is used in external link redirection.
Please help me how can i redirect the form action with getting value from that single field.

Comment: try to use a form_alter hook -> https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/form-api/forms-api-modify-forms-with-hook_form_alter

Then add a submit handler that redirects you wherever you want -> https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5861/how-to-redirect-to-a-page-after-submitting-a-form

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to a page after submitting a form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5861/how-to-redirect-to-a-page-after-submitting-a-form)

Comment: what u suggest are possible through modules but I have enabled a external theme mytheme.tpl.php and that theme contain a form field from which i have to take value and use that field value in external link @Insasse

Comment: Than just get the value from the form_state object in your submit handler and set it as redirect url.

Comment: If the form is directly in the template file, I would suggest to rebuild it programmatically in a module.

Comment: if i build the the form in module then how the form module will displayed on my default page with various all design of css & js.